# Default Certificate Validation Procedure

Tags: .net, wcf, security, ssl, certificate

Can somebody please give a description or (more preferably) a reference to how the .NET framework validates a domain certificate?

I am trying to connect to WCF service configured with a BasicHttpBinding with Certificate Transport security. The service is on machine 1 and the client on machine 2. Both machines are joined to a domain. The service certificate is issued by the domain's certification authority. However, when client (Visual Studio Add Service Reference Wizard in my case) is negotiating with the service it pops up a Warning message with three possible reasons that the certificate is untrusted:

1. The security certificate issued by a company is not in the untrust list. It might be trustable.
2. The security certificate date is valid.
3. **The security certificate for host 'Administrator' does not match the name of the page you are trying to view. (Warning!!)**

But i'm asking about reason 1, why?

On the other hand if i use WcfTestClient, it pops up the following error:

```
URI: https://ip:port/svc   
     Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://ip:port/svc'.   
     Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'ip:port'.   
     The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.   
     The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.HTTP GET Error.

URI: https://ip:port/svc   
    There was an error downloading 'https://ip:port/svc'.   
    The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.   
    The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

So can somebody please tell me what's happening around here? How is the service certificate validated? And please, don't tell me to write a PermissivePolicy to override the default procedure?

Answer (score 1):

You're hitting two checks here:

1. Certificate "subject" or "alternate name" field must match the hostname
2. The issuer of the certificate (or the original certificate, if it's self signed) must be added to "Root" certificate store on client machine

Fixing this error is simple - just re-issue the certificate(s) with the correct hostname and add the needed part to peer's "root" store.